# 301 from not www to www all URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all the URL not www with index.php in the path to the same in the www version.

I wrote this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/it/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.DOMAIN.it/$1/? [L,R=301]
```

but the result is:
https://www.DOMAIN.it/index.php/it/SOMETHING/

I need:
https://www.DOMAIN.it/SOMETHING/

what's wrong?
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/it/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ https://www.DOMAIN.it/$1/? [L,R=301]
```

The reason why `index.php` is appending to your redirected URL  is because the regex `(.*)` matches the full URL path and you just need to match a specific part of the URL or everything that comes bafter `/index.php` .

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I removed the request URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.domain\.it$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^index.php/it/(.*)$ https://www.domain.it/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

thanks